# how to understand "Classes must be defined before they are used " in php manual of keyword "extends"

Tags: php, extends

I get 2 php file
a.php

```
<?php
class A extends B {}
class B{}
```

php a.php
>>>no error

b.php

```
<?php
class A extends B {}
class B extends C {}
class C{}
```

php b.php
>>>> `Fatal error: Class 'B' not found in b.php on line 2`

According to [[php.net manual]](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php):

> Classes must be defined before they are used! If you want the class
>   Named_Cart to extend the class Cart, you will have to define the class
>   Cart first. If you want to create another class called
>   Yellow_named_cart based on the class Named_Cart you have to define
>   Named_Cart first. To make it short: the order in which the classes are
>   defined is important.

so anyboy pls explain why a.php get no "Fatal Error".

Comment: it behaves like a function :(

Comment: @MarkBaker it is giving same error as OP has stated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PHP [Inheritence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) doc.

> Unless autoloading is used, then classes must be defined before they
>   are used. If a class extends another, then the parent class must be
>   declared before the child class structure. This rule applies to
>   classes that inherit other classes and interfaces.

This example has no dependencies for class B and D:

```
<?php
 //This will work
 class A extends B {} //searches for class B in current document
 class B {}

 class C extends D{}
 class D{}
```

Class B depends on Class C

```
<?php
 //This will not work
 class A extends B {} //searches for class B in current document but class B has dependencies
 class B extends C {}
 class C{}
```

For includes and require, you must include the file before you use a declared function/class within that file.

Also see [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: i still puzzled by 2 points  1.why the __autoload function triggered while i haven't called it explicitly  2.if this trigged __autoload to find the class in current file, why doesn't b.php works? or this will not be trigged recursively? many thanks ;）

Comment: Autoload function is not triggered in this case. You need to write some code to autoload class in php. I haven't tried but using autoload might solve this problem. Here is a nice tutorial on using autoload in php http://www.codeforest.net/autoload-your-classes-in-php

Comment: i just tried...autoload is not triggered here, and this function will not solve the problem, because load the file itself will cause another undefine proble.

Comment: it seemed that the key  is why double dependencies make problem while single not